# How to change CC of redis in Makefile

Tags: makefile, redis

I need to change the compiler suit of Redis, which for **POWERPC**, so I did try to modify the Makefile, but cannot find the place to assign `CC`.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

The Makefile is at [Makefile](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/Makefile), around line 128.

Comment: `CC` is an [implicit make variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) so you can reassign it pretty much anywhere -- including the command line: `CC=/opt/bin/my_cc make ...` etc.

Answer (score 0):

That Makefile includes the line

```
-include .make-settings
```

which means "include the contents of the file `.make-settings`, if it exists."

I suggest you create such a file, with contents

```
 export CC = /path/to/desired/compiler
```

Comment: I can't actually try this suggestion right now. Let me know if it has problem and I'll look at it when I get home.